# Azure AD Code Grant from SPA?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does Azure AD support code grants from SPA apps?  I've built SPA apps that use the implicit flow against AAD and they work mostly fine.  The one caveat is that if we try to get group membership in the jwt tokens, you can only get up to 5 groups listed in the "group" claim otherwise the jwt contains a "hasGroups" claim (which is next to worthless).

I've come across some online article (which I can't seem to locate at the moment) that states the group claim is capped at 5 to prevent exceeding the url max values because of extra large access or id tokens being placed in the url, and that the code grant will allow for unlimited groups in the jwt because that request goes over a http post.

two questions:

1. It appears that I can't do a code grant from a SPA because the AAD
   token endpoint doesn't support CORS.  Is that true?  Why is that? 
   That seems like Microsoft admitting JS/SPA apps aren't first class
   citizens.  I've also tried to get the public keys from AAD from a
   client side app and found the lack of CORS on that endpoint as well.
2. Is it true that a code grant can get more than 5 groups back embedded in the jwt?

Comment: Why not get an access token for Microsoft Graph API and pull group membership from there? It's super effective. You could pull the user thumbnail photo and more.

Comment: We call the graph api from one of our api backends and it works, however the fact that AAD tokens are good for one and only one api means that all our apps now have to manage two tokens (one for our propitary api another for the graph api).  Getting two tokens in a SPA/JS app is pretty terrible with AAD.  Either do mulitple redirects to the IDP, or  do some nasty-ness in an iframe.  

Can we just get CORS on the token endpoint and do code grants from SPA/JS apps?

Comment: That would be a hack not a standards compliant implementation. There's a standard for this called OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant Type, and that nastiness is part of it. You should take it with the specs authors if you feel this isn't great. And it's not, i'm with you there, but there's so much you can do with having all secrets wide open in the user agent at all times. If you use adal.js there are methods that get both id_token and access tokens for you (yes they do the iframe backstabbing but what's your proposal, have the Authorization code in session storage instead, how's that more secure?)

Comment: I've read the oAuth2 spec and I didn't see anywhere where code grants can't be done from public clients.  It only says if your client is a public client you cannot send a secret.  So I'm not sure why allowing a code grant (without a secret) from a JS/SPA isn't in compliance with the oAuth2 spec.  In fact we use a couple IDPs that support this.

Comment: Wait, don't you need client_id and client_secret to send along with the code to exchange it for an access token?

Comment: no, not if your app is a public client.

Comment: So that piece of data (authorization code) if intercepted by an attacker is enough to issue a valid access token on behalf of the user.. This whole SPA OAuth situation is seriously broken no matter the flow..

Comment: Yeah... So that attack vector seems really small to me.  The auth code is only sent down to a url that is registered in AAD (and I believe https is required), so if that url is compromised it means the app that I have chosen to trust and registered as a reply url in AAD, has been compromised.  That's my fault, I shouldn't expect AAD to prevent my stupidity.